# Can I use both my on-board display adapter and a graphics card at the same time?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have a basic Lenovo desktop PC (running Windows 10) with an on-board display adapter and an HDMI port built-in.

I'd like to setup a second monitor to extend the one I have. Can I buy an entry level graphics card and use it alongside the on-board one at the same time?

I.e. plug one monitor to the on-board HDMI port and the other to the HDMI/DVI port on the added graphics card?

**UPDATE**: My machine is a Lenovo H530 (model no. 10130). Here are some details of the machine and BIOS taken from System Information.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**: The on-board display adapter is Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600.

Comment: Its a little hardware specific - could you mention what model it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your lenovo has Intel HD Graphics 4600. If yes, it can use 2 monitors.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your computer. Some BIOS settings allow you to use both onboard and a graphics card. It varies from manufacturer to manufacturer. Most computers nowadays have multiple display outputs and the processors can handle running all of the displays. If you do go the graphics card route, they typically come with multiple outputs as well.